# Prevent users from changing their passwords

Tags: windows-7, security

I tried to this method:

1. Open the Local Users and Groups manager.
2. In the left pane, click on Users.
3. In the middle pane, right click on the user account you want to do this with and click on Properties.

the problem is the user still can remove other users passwords (admin)

how to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stop an administrator from messing with others' user accounts, remove their administrator access. There is no way around this.

If they do not have administrator access, or permission to modify users, then they will not be able to change other users' passwords.

You cannot make someone an administrator and block them from performing administrator actions (i.e., changing user passwords).

Comment: so I can't set users privileges one by one?

Comment: @Star If they're in the Administrators group, they have free reign to do as they please on the system.  You should really consider whether they *really* need elevated privileges to do their work on the system.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can set user privleges one by one.  You will just need to edit their user profiles to do what you want them to be able to do.  You can do all of this in the managment windows under users.

Comment: If the users are in the Administrators group, as it seems they are, there's really little to nothing that you can do to effectively restrict their rights on the computer.

Comment: You might try creating a group policy with restrictions if you are able to do that.